# Model for the type-theoretic axiom of choice in Coq.

Tags: logic, reference-request, foundations, proof-theory, type-theory

This is the request for references.

It is a known fact that there is [a model of ZFC in ZF](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2279974/288417), so ZFC is consistent if ZF is consistent.

It is also know that there is a double-negation Godel-Gentzen translation from classical logic to intuitionistic.
(So we can prove something in IZF.)

Does exist a similar result about CIC with axiom of choice? By CIC I mean the [Calculus of Inductive Constructions](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/cic.html), the system which The Coq proof assistant is based on.

Does exist a model of CIC+choice inside CIC?
Where can I learn about it?

```
Definition choice :=
   forall (A B : Type) (P : A -> B -> Prop),  
   (forall a : A, exists b : B, P a b) ->
   exists f : A -> B, forall a : A, P a (f a).
```

Comment: Maybe Benjamin Werner's paper "[Sets in types, types in sets](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a44b/1b776e1363284c3c0467a2b5c26e67140f42.pdf)" is a good reading.

Comment: Isn't that the form of the axiom of choice that's actually provable in a dependent type theory like CIC?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I think that is not, because otherwise why would it be in the library https://github.com/coq-contribs/zfc ? (see Replacement.v)