# Can ZFC be proven from weak systems using consistency of those systems?

Tags: logic, philosophy, meta-math, formal-systems

Tl;dr Can we take a weak system $A_0$ then show

$$A_0 + Con(A_0)\implies Con(A_1)), \space A_1 + Con(A_1)\implies Con(A_2)), \space A_2 + Con(A_2) \implies \dots$$

terminating in ZFC?

My understanding of Hilbert's program was that after some crises in mathematics, people wanted to be sure ZFC didn't contain a hidden contradiction, and Hilbert's idea to do this was to prove it from weaker systems. In particular, a chain of systems might be found so that $A_0$ proves $A_1$ consistent, $A_1$ proves $A_2$ consistent, etc. so that the last system, $A_k$ is ZFC.

Godel's 2nd incompleteness theorem showed this to be impossible, as ZFC cannot prove its own consistency, so no weaker system can. However, this seems to me not a substantial problem, because [weaker systems like ZF can prove the consistency of ZFC *assuming the additional hypothesis Con(ZF)*.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2279974/1107685)

So in that case, it seems like (this part of) Hilbert's program is still very much possible in spirit, as one could instead take a weak system $A_0$ then show

$$A_0 + Con(A_0)\implies Con(A_1)), \space A_1 + Con(A_1)\implies Con(A_2)), \space A_2 + Con(A_2) \implies \dots$$
$$\dots \implies Con(A_k), \space A_k + Con(A_k) \implies ZFC$$

Which is still using a weaker system to show ZFC is consistent. There doesn't seem to be any reason this wouldn't be just as convincing to show ZFC consistent as the first approach.

So I would like to know whether this approach can be used to prove ZFC consistent starting from PA. If so, I would like to know if it's possible to prove it directly from PA, without intermediate systems. I would also be interested if any even weaker systems can be used.

I would also like to know if there is any philosophical reason this might be less convincing than the first approach.

Please also correct me if I have misunderstood Hilbert's program or the theorems I mentioned.

Comment: You write *If so, I would like to know if it's possible to prove it directly from PA, without intermediate systems*. In general, any proof of $A \implies B$ and any proof of $B \implies C$ may be chained together to give a direct proof of $A \implies C$.

Comment: @LeeMosher each statement isn't using just the conclusion of the previous statement, so it's not clear to me why that would still hold

Comment: Is $Con(A_1)$ meaningful inside the proof system of $A_0?$ I'm no expert in this field, but I feel that representing $A_1$ in $A_0$ would present problems.